# JavaScript print all used Unicode characters

Tags: javascript, unicode, character-encoding, character

I am trying to make JavaScript print all Unicode characters. According to my research, there are 1,114,112 Unicode characters.

A script like the following could work:

```
for(i = 0; i < 1114112; i++) 
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(i));
```

But I found out that only 10% of the 1,114,112 Unicode characters are used.

**How can I can I only print the used unicode characters?**

Comment: What do you mean by used characters?

Comment: Note that JavaScript strings are UTF-16, so you'll have to manage [surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF). And, the display of each character also depends on the font being used and whether it has a glyph defined for the code point. If you're trying to determine which code points the font supports, that information isn't generally made available in most JavaScript environments.

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond As I said in my question, "only 10% of the 1,114,112 Unicode characters are used."

Comment: @Progo: And what does "used" mean?

Comment: @Thanatos Since only 10% of the 1,114,112 possible Unicode characters are used, the rest is unused and reserved for future use.

Comment: Ah. "Assigned code point"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[As Jukka said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22740917/96656), JavaScript has no built-in way of knowing whether a given Unicode code point has been assigned a symbol yet or not.

There is still a way to do what you want, though.

I’ve written [several](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/node-unicode-data) [scripts](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/unicode-data) that parse the Unicode database and create separate data files for each category, property, script, block, etc. in Unicode. I’ve also created [an HTTP API](http://mathias.html5.org/data/unicode/) that allows you to programmatically get all code points (i.e. an array of numbers) in a given Unicode category, or all symbols (i.e. an array of strings for each character) with a given Unicode property, or a regular expression with that matches any symbols in a certain Unicode script.

For example, to get an array of strings that contains one item for each Unicode code point that has been assigned a symbol in Unicode v6.3.0, you could use the following URL:

```
http://mathias.html5.org/data/unicode/format?version=6.3.0&property=Assigned&type=symbols&prepend=window.symbols%20%3D%20&append=%3B
```

Note that you can prepend and append anything you like to the output by tweaking the URL parameters, to make it easier to reuse the data in your own scripts. An example HTML page that `console.log()`s all these symbols, as you requested, could be written as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>All assigned Unicode v6.3.0 symbols</title>
<script src="http://mathias.html5.org/data/unicode/format?version=6.3.0&property=Assigned&type=symbols&prepend=window.symbols%20%3D%20&append=%3B"></script>
<script>
  window.symbols.forEach(function(symbol) {
    // Do what you want to do with `symbol` here, e.g.
    console.log(symbol);
  });
</script>
```

[**Demo**](http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/all-unicode-symbols). Note that since this is **a lot** of data, you can expect your DevTools console to become slow when opening this page.

---

**Update:** Nowadays, you should use Unicode data packages such as [`unicode-11.0.0`](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/unicode-11.0.0#readme) instead. In Node.js, you can then do the following:

```
const symbols = require('unicode-11.0.0/Binary_Property/Assigned/symbols.js');
console.log(symbols);

// Or, to get the code points:
require('unicode-11.0.0/Binary_Property/Assigned/code-points.js');

// Or, to get a regular expression that only matches these characters:
require('unicode-11.0.0/Binary_Property/Assigned/regex.js');
```

Comment: The tools look interesting, but documentation is confusing. Anyway, your demo lists 249,703 codepoints, which is too much. From the official [Unicode 6.3 info](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.3.0/): “This addition brings the total number of characters assigned in the standard to 110,122. (That is the traditional count, which totals up graphic and format characters, but omits surrogate code points, ISO control codes, noncharacters, and private-use allocations.)”

Comment: Exactly – `Assigned` means any code point that has been assigned a symbol, so it includes control characters etc.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Interesting… What is the number you’d expect? The code is here, btw: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/unicode-data/blob/f44d0b6f26803d68d8a20ff34f0ef605ffaf6dc0/scripts/utils.py#L104-L156 Do you spot any bugs?

Comment: I’d expect the number 110,122 mentioned in the standard. It seems that your code includes not only ISO control codes (which might be called “control characters”, rather debatably) but also Private Use codepoints (to which the standard specifically does *not* assign any characters) and surrogates (which are definitely not Unicode characters at all).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela [TR18](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Categories) says: “`Assigned` is equivalent to `\P{Cn}`, and matches all assigned characters (for the target version of Unicode). It also includes all private use characters. It is useful for avoiding confusing double negatives. Note that `Cn` includes noncharacters, so `Assigned` excludes them.” Based on that, it seems the output is correct — do you agree?

Comment: Note to self: for the definition of “non-characters”, see [section 16.7 of the Unicode standard](http://unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.3.0/ch16.pdf). By that definition it seems no non-characters are included in the output. I also don’t see any private use code points. Does `http://mathias.html5.org/data/unicode/format?version=6.3.0&property=Assigned&type=code-points&prepend=window.codePoints%20%3D%20&append=%3B` contain anything else it shouldn’t?

Comment: `Assigned` is a property of code points: it specifies whether a meaning has been assigned to it. This does not mean that all code points with that property would be “Unicode characters”.

Comment: So the output is correct, it’s just not 100% applicable to OP’s question?

Comment: Please change demo link to https, as http won't work. Mixed Content error in console.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way in JavaScript to find out whether a code point is assigned to a character or not, which appears to be the question here. You need information extracted from suitable sources, and this information needs to be updated whenever new characters are assigned in new versions of Unicode.

There are 1,114,112 code points in Unicode. The Unicode standard assigns to each code point the property gc, General Category. If the value of this property is anything but Cs, Co, or Cn, then the code point is assigned to a character. (Code points with gc equal to Co are Private Use code points, to which no character is assigned, but they may be used for characters by private agreements.)

What you would need to do is to get a copy of some relevant files in the Unicode character database (just a collection of files in specific formats, really) and write code that reads it and generates information about assigned code points. For the purposes of printing all Unicode characters, it might be best to generate the information as an array of ranges of assigned codepoints. And this would need to be repeated when the standard is updated with new characters.

Even the rest isn’t trivial. You would need to decide what it means to print a character. Some characters are control characters that may have an effect such as causing a newline, but lacking a visible glyph. Some (spaces) have empty glyphs. Some (combining marks) are meant to be rendered as marks attached to preceding character, though they have conventional renderings as “standalone” characters, too. Some are meant to take essentially different shapes depending on nearest context; they may have isolated forms, too, but just writing a character after another by no means guarantees that an isolated form is used.

Then there’s the problem of fonts. No single font can contain all Unicode characters, so you would need to find a collection of fonts that cover all of Unicode when used together, preferably so that they stylistically match somehow.

So if you are just looking for a compilation of all printable Unicode characters, consider using the [Unicode code charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/).

Comment: Everything in this post is absolutely true, but it doesn’t really answer the question. Here’s how OP can do what they’re after: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22755675/96656

Answer (score 0):

The trouble here is that Javascript is *not*, contrary to popular opinion, a Unicode environment.

Internally, it uses `USC-2`, an incompatible 16-bit encoding method that predates UTF16.

In addition, many of the unicode characters are not directly printable by themselves -- some of them are modifies for the previous characters -- for example the Spanish letter `ñ` can be written in unicode either as a single point -- that character -- or as two points -- `n` and `~`

Here are a couple of resources that should really help you in understanding this:

- http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding
- http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela It does help though, since OP’s suggested use of `String.fromCharCode` wouldn’t work correctly for astral symbols.